# Xdebug and Shopware don't work

Tags: php, xdebug, ioncube, shopware

I try to use Xdebug(2.3.3/2.4.1) with Shopware, but i get an error (apache2/error.log):

```
AH00051: child pid 6523 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /tmp/apache-coredumps
```

Gdb core:

```
[New LWP 6394]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  xdebug_add_stack_frame (zdata=zdata@entry=0x7f2d185ec6e0, op_array=op_array@entry=0x7f2d1a7131e8, type=type@entry=2) at /tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug_stack.c:1096
1096    /tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug_stack.c: No such file or directory.
```

Do you have any idea? Thanks.

#### UPDATE

Ok, i know now. I 've disabled the Ioncube extension (Lizenz-Manager Plugin in Shopware) in backend. I have commented this extension in php.ini too.

Comment: Please read http://www.stackoverflow/help/mcve . In order to help, we need a way of reproducing your problem, usually in the form of code. As is you're saying "it's not working", but we hard have any context or way of reconstructing your problem. AND what do you make of the closing "No such file or directory" message, do  you have a file named `/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug_stack.c` Did you do something in your config related to `/tmp/pear/temp`? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You are right. I mean when xdebug is enabled and i go to my site than i get any atwort (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE). This error get only with Shopware.